# Changing positioning of elements depending on user screen size. How do I stack these elements for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, footer

I'm currently designing a website and there's a problem regarding the website footer.

When viewed on Desktop, the footer looks like this:
[Website Footer viewed on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tcsh.png)

The code used to create this look is:

```js
<meta name="color:Footer Background Color" content="#000000">
```

```css
CSS CODE

/*-----------------------------
        footer
-----------------------------*/
.bottom-footer {
    background-color: solid #ffffff;
}
.bottom-footer, .bottom-footer a, .back-to-top a {
    color: solid #000000;
}
.footer-message {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:500px;
}
 .bottom-footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1
}
.bottom-footer p {
    font-size: 1.4rem
}
.footer-message {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-left: 20px
}
.creation {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 1.4rem
}
.back-to-top {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 30px
}
.back-to-top a {
    font-size: 3rem;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out
}
.back-to-top a:hover {
    opacity: .5;
    text-decoration: none
}
.back-to-top .fa-angle-up {
    font-size: 4rem
}
footer.bottom-footer {
        height: 150px
    }
    .footer-message {
        padding: 40px 0 0
    }
    .creation,
        padding: 10px 0 0
    }
    .creation,
    .footer-message {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0
    }
    .back-to-top {
        margin-top: 0;
        top: 0
    }
```

```html
HTML CODE

<footer class="bottom-footer">
    <p class="footer-message">
        <a href="/" style="font-size:1.4rem">Home</a>
        <a href="/about" style="font-size:1.4rem">About</a>
        <a href="/news" style="font-size:1.4rem">News</a>
        <a href="/musings" style="font-size:1.4rem">Musings</a>
        <a href="/music" style="font-size:1.4rem">Music</a>
        <a href="/media" style="font-size:1.4rem">Media</a>
        <a href="/shows" style="font-size:1.4rem">Shows</a>
        <a href="/store" style="font-size:1.4rem">Store</a>
        <a href="/contact" style="font-size:1.4rem">Contact</a>
        <a href="/ask" style="font-size:1.4rem">Ask</a>
    </p>
    <a class="back-to-top" href='#'>^<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
    <div class="creation" style="text-decoration:none">
        © 2016 Sam Joel Nang. All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
</footer>
```

Now the problem is, when (for example) the window's width is decreased, the footer elements seem to scatter, the .creation element goes out of the footer and goes below.

What I want to do (when website is viewed in small window width, or on Mobile Devices screens) is to 'center' and 'stack' the footer elements (.footer-message, .back-to-top, and .creation) in the following order: top: .back-to-top, middle: .footer-message, and bottom: .creation, with the Footer Background Color still #ffffff. A small photo edit can represent what I mean:
[Ideal Website Footer look on Mobile Device or small Desktop window width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLWh9.png)

I hope someone can help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Introducing media queries**

In order to achieve what you're looking for, you can use media queries in CSS.

For example, if you want to stack the footer elements at a screen width of `480px` or less, the following media query will allow you to style for that scenario only:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  // Styles here
}
```

Given that, let's get on to the point of stacking. You have different position attributes currently on the elements you're trying to stack. The easiest way to stack elements on top of one another is to use the properties `display: block;` and `float: left;`. This way, the elements will span the width of their container and appear in the order they are in inside the document's HTML.

Let's take a look at how you might go about that:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .footer-message {
        float: left;
        display: block;
    }
    // center the links inside footer-message
    .footer-message a {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .creation {
        margin: 0 auto; // center it
        display: block;
    }
    .back-to-top {
        position: relative; // absolute positioning removes the element from document flow so we want to go relative
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto; // center it
    }
}
```

Note I simply removed the other properties since they're applied at all screen sizes already. You may want to alter those inside this media query in case the new styles affect their layout or you'd like it to differ for mobile.

Hope that helps!

UPDATE: I just noticed the part about you wanting to center the elements, I've added some code above to do so.

Comment: You're very welcome, if you could mark my answer correct/up-vote it that would be much appreciated!